# Convert YAML to XML in Ruby?

Tags: xml, ruby, nokogiri, yaml, converters

Are there any scripts out there, or have any of you built a tool, to convert YAML to XML using Nokogiri?  If not, any suggestions or samples?

Comment: Phrogz has a nice answer for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966180/how-to-create-xml-from-yaml-file-using-nokogiri/7971492#7971492

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any for Nokogiri, but if you just want the structure of the data, it is quite simple with ActiveSupport:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'
YAML.parse("key: value").transform.to_xml
```