# How to create XML from Yaml file using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, yaml

I want to read and open an .yml file and create an XML using Nokogiri ? Can anybody tell me how to do it ?

This is the Yaml format:

```yaml
getOrderDetails: 
  Id: '114'
  Name: 'XYZ'
```

This is the XML I need:

```xml
<product> <id>123</id> <name>xyz</name> </product>
```

And this is the ruby file:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
require 'rubygems'
require 'spec/spec_helper'
require 'yaml'

@doc = YAML.load(File.open(File.expand_path('/Workspace/XML_Parsing/getDetails_api.yml'‌​)))
@doc = File.open('/Workspace/XML_Parsing/getDetails_api.yml')
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.doc {
    @doc.each do |o|
      o.doc.child {
        puts "eval(#{doc(:getDetails(['Id']))})"
        puts "#{doc['NameCode']}"
        #o.OrderNo
        #o.EnterpriseCode
      }
    end
  }
end

puts builder.to_xml
```

Comment: insufficient information: example of a (small and concise) YAML covering all cases and how the generated XML for that example should look.

Comment: This is the yaml format
product:
  id: 123
  name: xyz

This is the output i need ...



<product>
 <id>123</id>
 <name>xyz</name>
</product>

Comment: can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more details.  Also bumps your question (don't do it just to bump!)  Also, you can add a bounty after the required waiting period.  Click to read about bounties in the [faq#bounty].

Answer (score 2):

If you know the fields you want specifically:

```
require 'yaml'
require 'nokogiri'

yaml = "getOrderDetails:
  Id: '114'
  Name: 'XYZ'"
doc = YAML.load yaml

output = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.product{
    xml.id   doc["getOrderDetails"]["Id"]
    xml.name doc["getOrderDetails"]["Name"]
  }
end
puts output.to_xml
#=> <?xml version="1.0"?>
#=> <product>
#=>   <id>114</id>
#=>   <name>XYZ</name>
#=> </product>
```

If you want to create an arbitrary XML file based on the names of Yaml keys:

```
output = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.product{
    doc["getOrderDetails"].each do |name,value|
      xml.send(name.downcase,value)
    end
  }
end
puts output.to_xml
#=> <?xml version="1.0"?>
#=> <product>
#=>   <id>114</id>
#=>   <name>XYZ</name>
#=> </product>
```

Comment: Nice answer! (with characters added to allow the comment. :-)